# How to delete columns from a table variable in MATLAB based on (relative) number of missing data points without using a loop

Tags: matlab, missing-data

I have a large table variable with lots of NaNs. In some columns there are only a few numbers missing, while in other columns the majority of values are NaN. Before excluding **rows** containing NaNs I would therefore like to remove all **columns** which consist of 20% or more NaNs. How can I approach this without using a loop?

Comment: `A(:,~(sum(isnan(A),1)>=0.2*size(A,1)))`?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the table variable type and produces an empty array when used on a double variable.

Comment: I think you need to convert that to a numeric array, `table2array` maybe?

Comment: I have considered that, but that creates the problem of keeping track of which columns have been deleted. Each column in my table represents the price time series for one asset whose ticker is the column header (which is retained in the table variable). If I separate the data from the tickers and then delete some of the data columns, I won't know how to delete the corresponding ticker with each deletion.

Comment: To keep track of which columns have been deleted you could store indexes  
inds = sum(isnan(A),1) >= 0.2*size(A,1)  
separate headers from table and delete corresponding headers with
hds(inds) = []

Answer (score 1):

To exclude such columns without loop you could use

```
A = A(:, sum(isnan(A),1) < 0.2*size(A,1))
```

or

```
A(:, sum(isnan(A),1) >= 0.2*size(A,1) ) = []
```

If you data is a table possible you could use following code

```
hds = table2array(inptable(1,:))
inpdata = table2array(inptable(2:end,:))
inds = sum(isnan(A),1) >= 0.2*size(A,1)
inpdata = inpdata(:, inds)
hds = hds(:, inds)
```

Comment: This works nicely on a double variable but is not defined for the table variable type. I am reading data from Excel and need to keep track of which column belongs to which header from the Excel file (in this case each column corresponds to a time series of asset prices and the header contains the stock ticker).